# Can a broken prong stuck in an outlet increase electrical consumption?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I looked at my outlets today the top is fine but the bottom ones all have a prong broken off stuck inside. I always wondered is this why my electric bill is so high! Please can someone tell me if broken prongs in outlets drain my electricity!!??

Comment: Just get a pair of properly insulated electrician's pliers and pull the prongs out. Turn the power off first if you are at all worried.

Comment: They *all* have a prong broken off stuck inside? That's very curious! Perhaps you are mistaken in your observations. You should get someone with experience to look at them.

Comment: Could you add a picture?

Comment: Is it actually a broken prong, or does the outlet have some kind of spring to help keep a plug from falling out?

Comment: VTC (on the pretense that there's no picture) where actually the OP is on a wild goose chase to find power consumption, and people are suggesting doing something likely beyond your skill set or what might not even be necessary.

Comment: No. It is not possible.  You need to complete a circuit for power to be drawn.

Comment: It's not how much your bill is:  it's how many kilowatt-hours you are using.  Are you using much more than, say,  a year ago?  Have you added new appliances?  An EV car charger?   A teenager who runs a space heater 24/7?  and so on.

Comment: A more effective way of finding out why your bill is so high is to wait until the meter is whizzing round quickly, then start turning off circuits at the breaker box until it stops going round so quickly.. Then investigate everything on that circuit. Maybe someone left a water heater turned on etc

Comment: If they are all like that it sounds like it was intentional.  It is certainly not normal, so you should find out why regardless of the electric bill.  Please post a picture.  In the US the two flat openings are for power and the round one that is usually on the bottom is for ground.  When you say the bottom, do you mean the ground connection or the lower receptacle in a duplex outlet?  If it is the ground and they are all like that, they are probably trying to tell you the ground is not connected.  It still won't matter to your power bill.

Answer (score 14):

A prong by itself cannot make a complete circuit. Even if it did, it would immediately trip your circuit breaker and likely damage the receptacle (as in it would visibly spark/arc). It doesn't sound they they're on the surface either, or they would be a shock hazard.

If I were you, and you feel confident enough to turn the power off, you could replace it easily with a new receptacle. It's just a matter of unscrewing and screwing with wires. Take a picture of the wires before you disconnect them.

Comment: @Ray take a photo of the wire positions before you start... or draw a quick sketch.

Comment: Presumably the presence of these prongs means that grounded plugs can't be inserted. In the UK, the earth pin is often used to open the shutters of the other two holes: do US receptacles have shuttered openings like UK sockets do?

Comment: @AndrewLeach tamper resistant sockets do.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - presumably, indeed, which this answer does too much.

Comment: If someone is asking if a prong can complete a circuit, presumably they are not in a position to attempt any electrical work. It may be worth not encourage DIY in this particular instance.

Comment: @GManNickG It would be kinda silly to ask a question on a DIY site and **not** get an answer that suggests a DIY path. Replacing an outlet isn't that hard (if you take a picture of the old outlet wiring) and it's the easiest way to fix the problem. An electrician would probably charge you $75 just to come out, let alone replace a $1-2 outlet

Comment: @Machavity Not that hard if you know what you're doing. Replacing an electrical outlet can get you killed if you don't know what you're doing, like doing a live-neutral short across your hands. You'll be long dead before it trips even the weakest 3A fuse.  THe concept of having a "prong stuck in an outlet" is just outright strange. We don't know what the OP is observing.

Comment: Some people are indeed capable of screwing-up replacing an outlet. Based on the vague description by OP, it's very likely OP doesn't have a clue how and why it works. Better not touch it then. A lot of people don't need an electrician for this, but some do.

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming US plugs here. No, broken prongs will not cause an increase in your electrical bill. In order for electricity to be used and appear on your bill electricity must move from one side of the top row to the other side of the top row in a circuit, through an electrical device of some kind. If you jumped directly from one side to the other with a wire it could cause an overload and blow a circuit breaker, so that clearly isn't happening, and it would happen so fast it wouldn't add to your electric bill.

The bottom prong is for grounding, which is an electrical safety mechanism, if there's a short in the appliance the energy will go there into the ground instead of through you, so it's very important you get this fixed. You could pull them out, I'd personally be concerned that the outlets have been damaged, which could be dangerous, and I would replace them. If you aren't confident about that type of work do not attempt it yourself.

Comment: Both these answers make presumptions, but at least this one says *do not attempt*, because we don't know what the OP is looking at and, the only safe assumption to make : neither do they.